# How do you set "bgp_settings" block in Azure azurerm_virtual_network_gateway resource?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

currently struggling trying to define the *bgp_settings* block in **azurerm_virtual_network_gateway** resource.

I have defined the following:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "Customer" {
  name                = var.vng_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  type     = "Vpn"
  vpn_type = "RouteBased"

  active_active = true
  enable_bgp    = true
  sku           = "VpnGw1"
  generation = "Generation1"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "vnetGatewayConfig1"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.Customer_IP1.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.gateway_subnet.id
  }

ip_configuration {
    name                          = "vnetGatewayConfig2"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.Customer_IP2.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.gateway_subnet.id
  }

bgp_settings {
    asn                           = 65000
    peering_addresses {
        apipa_addresses           = ["169.254.21.1"]
        ip_configuration_name     = azurerm_public_ip.Customer_IP1.name
    }
    peering_addresses {
        apipa_addresses           = ["169.254.21.5"]
        ip_configuration_name     = azurerm_public_ip.Customer_IP2.name
    }                
    }               
}
```

but getting errors because of both the *peering_addresses* sub-block definitions. If I remove them , all is correctly deployed but with no APIPA addresses.

Is there anyone who configured the above already? Unfortunately, I did not find any good example so far.

Thank you so much.

Comment: What are the errors? Can you add that to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must also configure the block `azurerm_virtual_network_gateway_connection`

[image]
[image]
More info https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_network_gateway_connection

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I know ```azurerm_virtual_network_gateway_connection``` needs to be configured and ```azurerm_local_network_gateway``` as further resources in order to create the IPSEC connection with the local on-prem gateways (it perfectly works if manually created). `As explained in my initial question, the issue I'm getting is related to the  ```peering_addresses {}``` only:  anyone already got a chance to deployed it? any example?

Answer (score -2):

In case it helps someone, the problem is that in the "ip_configuration_name" parameter you have configured the name of the public IP and you have to configure the name of the IP configuration ejm:

```
bgp_settings {
     asn = 65000
     peering_addresses {
         apipa_addresses = ["169.254.21.1"]
         ip_configuration_name = "vnetGatewayConfig1"
     }
     peering_addresses {
         apipa_addresses = ["169.254.21.5"]
         ip_configuration_name = "vnetGatewayConfig2"
     }
     }
}
```